# Remove whitespace between two ListView inside Column in Dialog - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, flutter-listview

I need to show two ListViews inside a dialog; I am using the showDialog function and in the "content" attribute I added a "SizedBox" without any value for the "height" attribute, and the lists are inside the Column object. Here is the code:

```
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        content: SizedBox(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text('Text1'),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: listOne.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Text(listOne.elementAt(index).name);
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Text('Text 2'),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: listTwo.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Text(listTwo.elementAt(index).name);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I have already checked that the item count for both lists is correct.
Here is the result:
[image]

I want to remove the big whitespace between the two lists if it possibile.
Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Expanded`: A widget that expands a child of a Row, Column, or Flex so
> that the child fills the available space.

so by default it will expand fills the full height of screen.

### Workaround:

change with `Flexible` widget:

> unlike `Expanded`, `Flexible` does not require the child to fill the available space.

```
children: [
  Text('Text1'),
  Flexible(
    child: ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemCount: 3,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text('.name');
      },
    ),
  ),
  Text('Text 2'),
  Flexible(
    child: ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemCount: 4,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text('.name');
      },
    ),
  ),
],
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The white space is coming for the `Expanded` widget trying to expand to full size extent of the screen for both lists. if you change the `Expanded` widget with `Sizedbox` and give it a height for both list it will remove the white space in between and after.

I hope this helps